# Coding and debugging an Outlook Add-in

Tags: debugging, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

As a personal project, I want to understand how to develop an outlook add-in. I sucessfully followed the [following tutorial provided by outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial) . I am now personnalizing my add in by changing the function of the button - I want to be able to send a personnalized mail when clicking on the button. I tried some coding but it is not working however I have no idea how to debugg my add in in outlook. I tried the following [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging) but it does not work in my case. The following folder`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\{[Outlook profile GUID]}\[Outlook mail account encoding]\Javascript\[Add-in ID]_[Add-in Version]_[locale]` does not exist on my system and hence I can not acess to file `bundle.js` as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest)

I did remove and re-installed my add-in but it did not change anything.
Please any help would be welcome as I am completely stuck because I don't have any way to log error or variables.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging Office Add-ins is essentially the same as debugging any web application. However, a single set of tools won't work for all add-in developers. This is because add-ins can be developed on different operating systems and run cross-platform. The [Overview of debugging Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview) article helps you find the detailed debugging guidance for your development environment.

For example, Office Add-ins running on Windows can be debugged against the Edge Chromium WebView2 runtime directly in Visual Studio Code, see [Use the Visual Studio Code debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium#use-the-visual-studio-code-debugger) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I actually used inspect properties inside my outlook desktop applications and it worked.